# Fade effect with timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set a timer for a fade effect? Say text1 will fade out in 5 seconds, then text2 will appear, then it will fade out after 5 seconds, then text3 will appear. I'm not knowledgeable in jQuery.

Say I have 3 texts:

```
<div class= "text1>Text 1</div>
<div class= "text1>Text 2</div>
<div class= "text1>Text 3</div>
```

I have only this:

```
$(".text1").fadeOut(5000); //now that a timers.
```

Comment: you can use $.each for iterate your element and wrap it into setTimeout, you will get fadeOut animate from text1 then text2 and so on with delay 5second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, fix your invalid HTML and use different classes (ids would work, too, btw):

```
<div class="text1">Text 1</div>
<div class="text2">Text 2</div>
<div class="text3">Text 3</div>
```

Then use this JavaScript code:

```
function fade() {
    $('.text1').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    $('.text2').delay(5000).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    $('.text3').delay(10000).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(fade);
}
fade();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/hmRFB/1/

Comment: could you tweak it a bit so if it reaches to text3 it will fadeout then text1 will reappear and the process will redo again.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply nest the callbacks. The function fadeOut takes 2 parameters, nr1 is how long time the animation should be, parameter nr2 is the callback that execute when the animation has completed.

http://jsfiddle.net/HULvL/

```
$(".text1").fadeOut(5000,function (){
// Text1 is outfaded..
    $(".text2").fadeOut(5000,function (){
        $(".text1").fadeIn(5000,function (){
            // Do more stuff
        })
    })
});​

<div class= "text1">Text 1</div>
<div class= "text2">Text 2</div>
<div class= "text3">Text 3</div>​
```

Comment: Its awsome for situation like this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Animate Banner Text fit for your questions. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/bTLd6/)

HTML Code ( your HTML code is correct, You create effective selector ) :

```
<div class= "text1">Text 1</div>
<div class= "text1">Text 2</div>
<div class= "text1">Text 3</div>
```

Jquery Code :

```
$(document).ready( function(){  

    function AnimateBannerTeks(){
        var ct= 1;      
        $('.text1').each( function(){           
            var delay= 5000 * ct;
            var $obj= $(this);
            setTimeout(
            function(){
                $('.text1').fadeOut('fast');
                $obj.fadeIn(5000);              
            }, delay);
            ct++;
        });
    }

    AnimateBannerTeks();
    setInterval(AnimateBannerTeks, 15000);
});
```